# Why isn't everything assignable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was raised with the "everything in JavaScript object-oriented and assignable" paradigm. So I lived my life happy, until...

```js
    var x = {};

    x.field = true;
    x.field.netType = "System.Boolean";
    
    alert(x.field.netType);
```

It compiles, but the alert keeps giving me 'undefined'. Why!?

Comment: Throw in `'use strict';` at the top and see the magic ;-)

Comment: @thefourtheye ? what would strict mode do here?

Comment: @Pointy Complain. It would complain. Strict mode is that picky girl who doesn't let you do the most tempting stuff, while non-strict mode is the oposite.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel hmm `(function() { "use strict"; (true).x = 0; })()` - I get no complaints.

Comment: @Pointy Now that's a surprise. A cool one. I guess that assigning to coarced values is strictly fine. They are object afterall, and aren't read-only objects.

Comment: "It compiles" no it doesn't. JavaScript is not a compiled language.

Comment: what this does is `new Boolean(x.field).netType = "System.Boolean"` but then the Boolean object is discarded.

Comment: @Pointy Actually, it should barf itself when running that piece. It seems that Firefox has a bug. It has the expected behaviour on Chrome.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yes, it works in Node 0.10 also.

Comment: @Pointy All V8 engine versions that support strict mode will barf. That's a nice point to add to your answer. Firefox and IE simply run it like if nothing happened.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel no, the older V8 in Node 0.10 doesn't barf, whether I enable strict mode with the special string or with the command line option. But Node 0.10 is pretty old.

Comment: @Pointy Then I should change my statement. I don't have Node.js to try it. I know that Chrome will chew itself when you try to run that piece of code, and another version of Node.js will as well.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yes my fresh Chrome doesn't like it. It complains that "x" is a read-only property.

Comment: That V8 behaviour is strange. I like it as a warning, but it shouldn't violate the spec, should it?

Comment: Hm, this *must* be a duplicate. Anyone?

Comment: @Bergi: Already looked and didn't find anything with a good answer. Btw, the spec says about strict mode *"The LeftHandSide also may not be a reference to a data property with the attribute value {[[Writable]]:false}, to an accessor property with the attribute value {[[Set]]:undefined}, nor to a non-existent property of an object whose [[Extensible]] internal slot has the value false. In these cases a TypeError exception is thrown (12.14)."* However, it doesn't look like `[[Extensible]]: false` is set when coercing primitives this way, so yeah, it looks like V8 is wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Primitives (strings, numbers, `true` and `false`) in JavaScript are **not** objects. However, when they are used with `.` or `[]` as if they *were* objects, the language obliges by implicitly constructing object wrappers for them.

In your example, that's what happened. The assignment to the object property did actually work, so there was no error, but that wrapper object was then immediately thrown away.

On the other hand:

```
var x = {};

x.field = new Boolean(true);
x.field.netType = "System.Boolean";

alert(x.field.netType);
```

(I wouldn't advise actually doing that; using objects made from the primitive wrapper types tends to have weird effects as those values propagate into code that doesn't expect them.)

Comment: Is there any documentation about this behavior?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker well there's the [language spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) but that's not easy reading. I would imagine that any good JavaScript reference would have to touch on this behavior, as it's pretty fundamental to the language. Something as common as checking the length of a string will cause implicit object wrapping.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: This may interest you: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20&%20grammar/ch3.md#boxing-wrappers . In the spec, the boxing is defined here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getvalue (but that's not really valuable without context, i.e. knowing how/where `GetValue` is called).

Comment: Warning: `new Boolean(false)` is a truthy value.

Comment: @Keen yes exactly, and `typeof new String("hello")` is `"object"`

Comment: `x.field = true; x.field.netType = "System.Boolean";` is actually working.  `x.field` which is a primitive boolean value is getting converted to object internally at the time of `x.field.netType = "System.Boolean"`  but we dont have a reference of it so immediately it becomes garbage. If we store the refrence of `x.field` so that it doesnt be garbage we can get the value. like this....`x.field = true;  var y = x.field.netType = "System.Boolean"; alert(y);`

Answer (score 10):

```
x.field = true; 
x.field.netType = "System.Boolean";
```

is actually working.
   `x.field` which is a primitive boolean value is getting converted to object internally but we dont have a reference of it so immediately it becomes garbage. If we store the refrence of `x.field` so that it doesnt be garbage we can get the value. like this....

```
x.field = true;  
var y = x.field.netType = "System.Boolean"; 
alert(y);
```

If you write you code like this

```
var x = {};

x.field = {};
x.field.netType = "System.Boolean";

alert(x.field.netType);
```

Then it will work.

In your code this line `x.field.netType = "System.Boolean";` will throw error in `strict mode

```
`//Cannot assign to read only property 'netType' of true`
```

**Why this line `x.field.netType` gives `undefined`**

Objects of this type are merely wrappers, their value is the primitive they wrap and they will generally coerce down to this value as required.

JavaScript will readily coerce between `primitives and objects`.

```
var a = 'Intekhab';
 a.length;//In this case the string value is coerced to a string object in order to access the property length.

var Twelve = new Number(12); 
var fifteen = Twelve + 3; // In this case Object Twelve is coerced to a primitive value.
fifteen; //15
```

If JavaScript detects an attempt to assign a property to a primitive it will indeed coerce the primitive to an object. This new object has no references and will immediately become fodder for garbage collection.

```
var primitive = "september";
primitive.vowels = 3;
//new object created to set property 
(new String("september")).vowels = 3;



primitive.vowels;
//another new object created to retrieve property 
(new String("september")).vowels; //undefined
```

Comment: This is only half the answer … it explains why you get `undefined`. but it does not explain why the assignment seems to work in first place. Apart from that, the question was not how to fix this, but what's the reason for this… the answer by @Pointy is *way* better.

Comment: This is not clear enough and "wrong" in some way because doing var t = new Boolean(); t.foo = "bar"; is actually working. It can mislead OP. @Pointy answer is more accurate atm.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to support your answer?

Answer (score 5):

`x.field` is a boolean value; boolean values are primitives and are read-only. When you attempt to assign a value to `x.field.netType`, you are attempting to modify the value of `x.field`. Pointy's answer mostly explains this.

When in 'normal' JavaScript mode, this results in the value simply being `undefined`.

The reason **why** someone in the comments suggested strict mode (which you should *definitely* be using) is that strict mode will throw an error informing you that you are attempting to assign a value to a read-only value and prevent you from doing that instead of silently returning `undefined` whenever you access that property.

```
'use strict';
var foo = true;
foo.bar = 'qux'; // this line will throw an Error
```

As per Pointy's example, **it does actually** error, at the very least on Node 4.0. I have no idea what JS engine Pointy is using but it is not operating correctly.

```
> (function() { 'use strict'; (true).x = 0; })()
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'x' of true
    at repl:1:38
    at repl:1:45
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:154:27)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:308:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:209:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:548:8)
```

Comment: @Pointy as I cannot comment on the main answer, your example and question about strict mode is here.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar your name suits you well! JavaScript is indeed a JIT compiled language and has been since *at least* IE9.

Comment: Noje.js uses the V8 engine (same as Chrome),  while we (me and Pointy) are using Firefox. In Firefox, it doesn't error out. But it does on the V8 engine.

Comment: It should be noted that this behavior *appears* to be violating the spec.